# how to build a screen sharing app on metro like the remote sharing in the store

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro, java-metro-framework

I'm developing an application for a k12 classrooms.I need to share what's the instructor do in the users (students) PCS. I wonder if I could share using webcam ...why I can't share any video on metro app ?

My app based on HTML5/JS

**My question is Is that possible to share the screen between devices or Broadcast the screen to other students in the classroom If it could be which libraries could support ???**

I've read that in Windows 8 Metro RTC app using the namespace Windows.Media.PlayTo namespace can stream audio, video, and images to remote devices. and I found some app for remote sharing like TeamViewer [remote sharing in the store](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/en-us/app/remote-desktop/051f560e-5e9b-4dad-8b2e-fa5e0b05a480).

thank you in advance

Comment: so are there any suggestion where to start ?